# How to split a row into 3 shorter rows in R

Tags: r

So I have a table in R like this:

```
id    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5     col6     col7     col8   col9 
101   1       1111    202     2       1120     5512     3        1221   900
102   1       2999    1110    2       2000     5000     3        80     200
103   1       1121    333     2       111      222      3        101    1000
. 
.
```

I'm trying to bring the long row for each subject into multiple rows like this:

```
id   trial   col1   col2   
101  1       1111   202
101  2       1120   5512
101  3       1221   900
102  1       2999   1110
102  2       2000   5000
102  3       80     200
103  1       1121   333
103  2       111    222
103  3       101    1000
```

I'd appreciate any help as I'm a R neophyte here. I imagine I'd want to read the col as a triplet and then compile them up but have no idea how to go about to do it.

Comment: See `melt` in your package of choice. Will also help to rename `col{1,4,7}`.

Comment: `tidyr` is another nice package for this.

Comment: @MichaelChirico melt seems like would be the way to go, but how would you use it in this case especially since I'll be collapsing multiple columns

Comment: See `melt` in the `data.table` package which accepts multiple `measure.vars` arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your data is the it is stored in a very unconventional way.  Generally when data is transformed from a wide format to a long format the variable names in the wide data become data points within the long data, hence the name pivot table.  To overcome this problem I suggest you transform the data as follows:

```
d <- d[, !grepl("col[147]", names(d))] 

names(d)[-1] <- paste(sort(rep(1:3, 2)), paste0("col", 1:2))
```

Once you have done this it is relatively straightforward to reshape the data with the `tidyr` package.

```
d %>%
  gather(key, value, -id) %>%
  separate(key, c("trial", "new"), sep = "\\s") %>%
  spread(new, value)
```

Comment: This works beautifully. What if you want to automate the progress even more. Say if the Trial number isn't in sequence or if it's in random string.

Comment: @KenLam you can always obtain the trial numbers as follows.  If you know which columns contain the trial numbers then `unique(d[, grepl("col[147]", names(d))])` will give you the trial numbers.   If you don't know which columns contain the trial number then you need to find them first.  To do so you will need to know something about the trial numbers.  For example, it might be the case that the trial numbers are a single digit and all other data will not be a single digit, then you could using something like this, `grep("^[0-9]$", d[2,], value=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

(A bit manual) What about this?

```
res <- cbind(rep(df[,1], each = nrow(df)), matrix(c(t(df[-1])), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(res) <- c("id", "trial", "col1", "col2")
res
       id trial col1 col2
 [1,] 101     1 1111  202
 [2,] 101     2 1120 5512
 [3,] 101     3 1221  900
 [4,] 102     1 2999 1110
 [5,] 102     2 2000 5000
 [6,] 102     3   80  200
 [7,] 103     1 1121  333
 [8,] 103     2  111  222
 [9,] 103     3  101 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `array`

```
cbind(rep(df1$id, 
  each=nrow(df1)),apply(aperm(array(unlist(df1[-1]), 
           dim=c(3,3,3)), c(3,2,1)), 2, c))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  101    1 1111  202
# [2,]  101    2 1120 5512
# [3,]  101    3 1221  900
# [4,]  102    1 2999 1110
# [5,]  102    2 2000 5000
# [6,]  102    3   80  200
# [7,]  103    1 1121  333
# [8,]  103    2  111  222
# [9,]  103    3  101 1000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 101:103, col1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), 
 col2 = c(1111L, 
 2999L, 1121L), col3 = c(202L, 1110L, 333L), col4 = c(2L, 2L, 
2L), col5 = c(1120L, 2000L, 111L), col6 = c(5512L, 5000L, 222L
 ), col7 = c(3L, 3L, 3L), col8 = c(1221L, 80L, 101L), 
col9 = c(900L, 
200L, 1000L)), .Names = c("id", "col1", "col2", "col3", 
"col4", 
"col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text1 = "
id    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5     col6     col7     col8   col9 
101   1       1111    202     2       1120     5512     3        1221   900
102   1       2999    1110    2       2000     5000     3        80     200
103   1       1121    333     2       111      222      3        101    1000
"

df1 <- read.table(text=text1, head=T, as.is=T)

library(plyr)

ddply(df1, .(id), function(df){
  df1 <- df[, 2:4]
  df2 <- df[, 5:7]
  df3 <- df[, 8:10]
  names(df1) <- c("trial", "col1", "col2")
  names(df2) <- c("trial", "col1", "col2")
  names(df3) <- c("trial", "col1", "col2")
  df.n <- do.call(rbind, list(df1, df2, df3))
  return(df.n)
})
#    id trial col1 col2
# 1 101     1 1111  202
# 2 101     2 1120 5512
# 3 101     3 1221  900
# 4 102     1 2999 1110
# 5 102     2 2000 5000
# 6 102     3   80  200
# 7 103     1 1121  333
# 8 103     2  111  222
# 9 103     3  101 1000
```